# what are the scenarios to be checked for time zone(UTC)

Tags: manual-testing

> **how to check Coordinated Universal Time UTC conversion for date field in the application for different location,region.**  or when we should go for UTC conversion and when not

Comment: flagged as too broad

Comment: Agreed. This needs a lot more context to be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Time conversion is **much more complicated** than you imagine, because different countries/locales switch to daylight saving time at different dates, it is not just one sweep change. And switching back is also not coordinated.

- http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/events.html
- http://www.timeanddate.com/time/us/arizona-no-dst.html

So to convert time between locations, you need to know also the date when conversion should be calculated.

http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html